# Application failed to run on Arch Linux with glibc package version 2.35-2

Tags: glibc

The strange thing is that teh glibc package version 2.35-2 does not contain /usr/lib/libdl.so nor /usr/lib/libpthread.so

Here is strace:

chilkat/chilkat-9.5.0-x86_64-linux-gcc/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v3/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: You couldn't even cut/paste _complete_ line? Have a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

`libdl.so` and `libpthread.so` are link editor input files, they are not used at run time. Instead, the sonames `libdl.so.2` and `libpthread.so.0` are used for run-time dynamic linking.

Starting with glibc 2.34, explicitly linking against `libdl` or `libpthread` is no longer needed (as all functions are provided by `libc` directly). Therefore, `libdl.so` and `libpthread.so` have been replaced by *empty* static archives `libdl.a` and `libpthread.a`, so that the linker arguments `-ldl` and `-lpthread` keep working.